# Questions about sudo

Tags: sudo, users

I have a couple of questions on using `sudo`:

1. Give Ben sudo access to the machine
2. Give Tim sudo access to the following tool : `iptables`

For (1) I just address Ben to the `sudo` group. So I did:

```
usermod -aG sudo Ben
```

and for the (2) I edited the `/etc/sudoers` file  with the `/usr/sbin/visudo` command and appended the following line

```
Tim ALL=(ALL) iptables
```

Is that correct and are there any other better ways ?

Comment: you didn't edit the /usr/sbin/visudo file; maybe you used visudo to edit the sudoers file?

Comment: One 'better' way is to let Tim run iptables without having to type in a password, which is very important in passwordless systems (e.g. if you log in via SSH key, you don't use nor need a password).  Do this by adding Tim like so: Tim ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: iptables

Comment: @Andrew, why not post that as an answer?  *I* would upvote it....  (You don't always have to write a full article to answer a question.)

Comment: Giving Tim root privileges when running *any* binary called iptables is a *very bad idea*.

Comment: I corrected the question to mention that `visudo` edits `/etc/sudoers`.

Answer (score 1):

To give Tim access to iptables, you can edit `/etc/sudoers`, with `visudo`:

```
tim ALL=NOPASSWD: /sbin/iptables
```

This will allow him to used the `iptables` as root without inputing his password. The path is full, for security reasons, otherwise if only `iptables` as you have, Tim would be able run any binary called `iptables` as root, and would be enough to create a script `iptables` residing at `~tim/bin/iptables` to escalate to root.

You can also create an alias in his `~/.bashrc`, so Tim does not need to be writing all the time `sudo /sbin/iptables` to be using `iptables` as root:

```
alias iptables='sudo /sbin/iptables'
```